# Package control in Sublime Text 3 no longer appearing when using keyboard shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3

I don't know of any other way to access Package Control, but i find it weird that it doesn't work anymore, could the installation of other packages have caused it to just stop working? I don't even know how to debug something like this or find a solution for it, it appears this doesn't happen to many people, but it surely is happening to me.

When i press cmd+shift+p i don't get the Package control window. My ST3 has been very buggy and no updates have ever been available.

Is there just a quick way to wipe it all clean and start over?

Thanks.

Comment: cmd+shift+p is the keyboard shortcut for the Command Palette, it does not link directly to Package Control. Does the shortcut do anything?

Comment: @APAD1 yes that is correct, and i do mean the Command Palette, that then allows you to search for Package Control. The shortcut does not do anything anymore, I know i could program the key bindings but i haven't looked that up yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to completely start from scratch, first exit Sublime, then delete `/Applications/Sublime Text.app`. Finally, delete `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3`.

You can now [re-download ST3](http://sublimetext.com/3) and reinstall [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation). Restart Sublime as instructed, and you should now be able to hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and open the Command Palette. Type in ***`packcon`*** to get the Package Control options. You'll need to reinstall all your plugins, and reset any custom preferences, keybindings, snippets, etc. you've made.

Good luck!